# How to auto-send password using runas command

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Using Python, I'm looking for a way to automatically use the `runas` command with a password stored in a file.

**runas instruction**

```
runas /user:NameOfUser cmd.exe < stored_password.txt
```

or

```
echo password |runas /user:NameOfUser cmd.exe
```

both of those instructions don't work.

While browsing through the different topics on this subject, I did not manage to get what I wanted.

Actually, I did a function such as this :

```
def runAsTest():
  row1 = f"runas /user:MyUser cmd.exe <  \"{DIR_PASSWORD}FILE_PSWD.txt\"\n"
  with open(f"{DIR_BATCH}runAsTest.bat", "w") as file:
    file.write(row1)

    print("runAsTest.bat created")

    try:
      os.system(f"start call \"{DIR_BATCH}runAsTest.bat\"")
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

but when I try my code, I've got this error : [image: CMD ERROR]

It happens, even if the password is correct in the txt file, maybe because of the hidden carriage return.

Comment: `runas.exe`, requests the password from the terminal, not from stdIn.

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done, since runas has been designed not to allow it. Having said that, you can use the Windows API from Python and use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` to achieve what you want. Just remember that it's a very, very bad idea to be storing passwords in plaintext. If you must, you have to wonder why the account even has a password in the first place.